# How to do mysql query based on the input textbox id?

Tags: php

I have a form with two input textboxs: mobile and extension, I want to provide an auto populate by jQuery to fill in another textbox like title, department and etc., I can do that like this

index.php

```
//form start
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" onchange = "mobilecheck();" size="10" maxlength="30" value="" />
<input type="text" name="extension" id="extension" onchange = "extensioncheck();" size="10" maxlength="30" value="" />
//form end
//auto populate work well so I skip those codes

//function start
var url = "check.php?q=";

function mobilecheck() {
   var idValue = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
   var myRandom=parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);  // cache buster
   if (idValue=="") return;
   http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
   http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
   http.send(null);
}

function extensioncheck() {
   var idValue = document.getElementById("extension").value;
   //the other are same with mobilecheck() so skip it
   //function end
```

use same php file to do the mysql query
check.php

```
//query start
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mycontact WHERE (mobile like '$q') or (extension like '$q')); 
//query end
```

it works well but I wonder is there a better way to do this like switch to combine two function in one.

any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended Use Memcache instead of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
//form start
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" onchange = "check('mobile');" size="10" maxlength="30" value="" />
<input type="text" name="extension" id="extension" onchange = "check('extension');" size="10" maxlength="30" value="" />
//form end

var url = "check.php?q=";

function check(type){
var idValue = document.getElementById(type).value;
var myRandom=parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);  // cache buster
if (idValue=="") return;
http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
http.send(null);
}
```

Comment: @user1705877, how to add a prefix for a mobile when send out the query? for mobile "12345678", add a prefix "001" , then send a query "001-12345678"

Comment: You get the value of mobile thru "document.getElementById(type).value"
try changing it to:

var idValue = 'prefix'+ document.getElementById(type).value;

If it only happens for mobile, add an if statement for type=mobile.

Comment: I use "if (document.getElementById(type).id == "mobile")" then "idValue ="fxclz"+idValue;", it worked!